# How to consistently sum lists of values contained in a table?

Tags: kdb

I have the following two tables:

```
t1:([]sym:`AAPL`GOOG; histo_dates1:(2000.01.01+til 10;2000.01.01+til 10);histo_values1:(til 10;5+til 10));

t2:([]sym:`AAPL`GOOG; histo_dates2:(2000.01.05+til 5;2000.01.06+til 4);histo_values2:(til 5; 2+til 4));
```

What I want is to sum the `histo_values` of each symbol across the `histo_dates`, such that the resulting table would look like this:

```
t:([]sym:`AAPL`GOOG; histo_dates:(2000.01.01+til 10;2000.01.01+til 10);histo_values:(0 1 2 3 4 6 8 10 12 9;5 6 7 8 9 12 14 16 18 14))
```

So the resulting dates `histo_dates` should be the union of `histo_dates1` and `histo_dates2`, and `histo_values` should be the sum of `histo_values1` and `histo_values2` across dates.

**EDIT:**

I insist on the union of the dates, as I want the resulting `histo_dates` to be the union of both `histo_dates1` and `histo_dates2`.

Comment: are you using the Q-JS-Promise library? If not, why [tag:q]? Use [tag:q-lang] instead. See [tag:q] description....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways. One would be to ungroup to remove nesting, join the tables, aggregate on sym/date and then regroup on sym:

```
q)0!select histo_dates:histo_dates1, histo_values:histo_values1 by sym from select sum histo_values1 by sym, histo_dates1 from ungroup[t1],cols[t1]xcol ungroup[t2]
sym  histo_dates                                                                                                   histo_values
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAPL 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 0 1 2 3 4 6  8  10 12 9
GOOG 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 5 6 7 8 9 12 14 16 18 14
```

A possibly faster way would be to make each row a dictionary and then key the tables on sym and add them:

```
q)select sym:s, histo_dates:key each v, histo_values:value each v from (1!select s, d!'v from `s`d`v xcol t1)+(1!select s, d!'v from `s`d`v xcol t2)
sym  histo_dates                                                                                                   histo_values
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAPL 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 0 1 2 3 4 6  8  10 12 9
GOOG 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 5 6 7 8 9 12 14 16 18 14
```

Another option would be to use a plus join `pj`:

```
q)0!`sym xgroup 0!pj[ungroup `sym`histo_dates`histo_values xcol t1;2!ungroup `sym`histo_dates`histo_values xcol t2]
sym  histo_dates                                                                                                   histo_values
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAPL 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 0 1 2 3 4 6  8  10 12 9
GOOG 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 5 6 7 8 9 12 14 16 18 14
```

See here for more on plus joins: https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/pj/

**EDIT:**
To explicitly make sure the result has the union of the dates, you could use a union join:

```
q)0!`sym xgroup select sym,histo_dates,histo_values:hv1+hv2 from 0^uj[2!ungroup `sym`histo_dates`hv1 xcol t1;2!ungroup `sym`histo_dates`hv2 xcol t2]
sym  histo_dates                                                                                                   histo_values
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAPL 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 0 1 2 3 4 6  8  10 12 9
GOOG 2000.01.01 2000.01.02 2000.01.03 2000.01.04 2000.01.05 2000.01.06 2000.01.07 2000.01.08 2000.01.09 2000.01.10 5 6 7 8 9 12 14 16 18 14
```

Comment: Are we sure that the resulting `histo_dates` will be the `union` of both `histo_dates1` and `histo_dates2`, if `count histo_dates1 < count histo_dates2`? I am afraid the `pj` will be equivalent to a `lj` for the resulting keys, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
// rename the columns to be common names, ungroup the tables, and place the key on `sym and `histo_dates
q){2!ungroup `sym`histo_dates`histo_values xcol x} each (t1;t2)

// add them together (or use pj in place of +), group on `sym
`sym xgroup (+) . {2!ungroup `sym`histo_dates`histo_values xcol x} each (t1;t2)

// and to test this matches t, remove the key from the resulting table
q)t~0!`sym xgroup (+) . {2!ungroup `sym`histo_dates`histo_values xcol x} each (t1;t2)
1b
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way using [functional amend](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/amend/)

```
//Column join the histo_dates* columns and get the distinct dates - drop idx
//Using a functional apply use the idx to determine which values to plus
//Join the two tables using sym as the key - Find the idx of common dates

(enlist `idx) _select sym,histo_dates:distinct each (histo_dates1,'histo_dates2),
            histovalues:{@[x;z;+;y]}'[histo_values1;histo_values2;idx],idx from 
                update idx:(where each histo_dates1 in' histo_dates2) from ((1!t1) uj 1!t2)
```

One possible problem with this is that to get the idx, it depends on the date columns being sorted which is usually the case.